# Dont see system.io.ports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I'm using VS2022 and wanted to use `getportnames()`.

But I notice when I wrote using that intellisense doesn't come up with the last instance.

I see system.io but Ports doesn't come up. Anyone has an idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the nuget package System.IO.Ports, e.g. in your csproj:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="System.IO.Ports" Version="6.0.0" />
```

### How to find these packages

You could find it this way:

1. Check the namespace and assembly on the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0. Here both System.IO.Ports. Also double check the platform support, under *Applies to*.
2. Search for System.IO.Ports on nuget.org: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=System.IO.Ports and select the Microsoft package